# What is the name for a removable sewn bag stitch?

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

This stitch is composed of a single string/thread and is common on dogfood and grain sacks. It can be removed by just pulling on the end. Here is an example I found on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-NHxRwds4g).

Thanks!

Comment: More important:  how come this release mechanism fails to work on 2 out of three bags :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called "chain stitch" and was the stitch used in the first designs of sewing machines, because it is easy to produce mechanically. The fact that it can be pulled out unless the end of the string is knotted (as explained in the OP's video link) is a disadvantage for most purposes. For example, if the string breaks one side of the break will often quickly unravel.

The standard sewing machine stitch is now "lock stitch" which uses two threads, not one, and can't be pulled undone in the same way. Chain stitch is only used for special applications, or as decoration.

See https://home.howstuffworks.com/sewing-machine1.htm for an animation of how both stitches are made by machine.